# What makes an econometric model robust?

Tags: regression, econometrics, robust

I was reading a paper on robustness (http://econ.ucsb.edu/~doug/245a/Papers/Robustness%20Checks.pdf) and they say:

"To determine whether one has estimated effects of interest, $\beta$; or only predictive coefficients, $\hat{\beta}$ one can check or test robustness by dropping or adding covariates."

What does a model being robust mean to you? Is this the only way to consider it in  an econometric sense?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this [Hal Varian paper:](http://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/jep.28.2.3)

> Many papers in applied econometrics present regression results in a
>   table with several different specifications: which variables are
>   included in the controls, which variables are used as instruments, and
>   so on. The goal is usually to show that the estimate of some
>   interesting parameter is not very sensitive to the exact specification
>   used. One way to think about it is that these tables illustrate a
>   simple form of model uncertainty: how an estimated parameter varies as
>   different models are used. In these papers the authors tend to examine
>   only a few representative specifications, but there is no reason why
>   they couldn’t examine many more if the data were available.

I would also add that the effect may change when you alter the covariates or the sample, but it should do so in a predictable and theoretically consistent manner to be called robust.

There are other sense of robust that are often used and are somewhat related: robust to heteroskedasticity or autocorrelation, outliers, and various assumption violations (like error distributions).

Comment: Interesting! In your opinion, do you think it makes more sense to start with a larger model (including core covariates, and others) and then show that the core covariates don't change when removing some of the "others". Or begin with a smaller model and add?

Comment: That's a tough question. There are several competing philosophies of variable selection that depend on the researchers' ultimate goals. Personally, I use economic theory to pick a preferred specification that is relatively parsimonious. Then I test down a general variant of that specification that encompass rival theories. At times, I have used regularization on a less carefully selected set of variables.